# Automatic change of defaultdict (python 3)

Tags: count, python-itertools, callable, defaultdict, python-2to3

I encounter a problem while translating from python2 to python3 the following line:

```
fmap = defaultdict(count(1).next)
```

I changed `count(1).next` to `next(count(1))`

but get this error:

> fmap = defaultdict(next(count(1))) TypeError: first argument must be
>   callable or None

I guess this line intend to assign new default value each time. Do you have suggestions? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear - the first argument to a `defaultdict` must be a callable (function for example, or class name), or None. This callable will be called in case a key does not exist to construct the default vale. On the other hand:

```
next(count(3))
```

will return an integer, which is not callable, and makes no sense. If you want the `defaultdict` to default to an increasing a number whenever a missing key is used then something close to what you have is:

```
>>> x=defaultdict(lambda x=count(30): next(x))
>>> x[1]
30
>>> x[2]
31
>>> x[3]
32
>>> x[4]
33
```

Comment: Working - Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

The `.next()` method on iterators has been renamed in Python 3.  Use `.__next__()` instead.

**Code**

```
fmap = defaultdict(count(1).__next__)
```

**Demo**

```
fmap["a"]
# 1

fmap["b"]
# 2
```

Note, `defaultdict` needs a callable argument, something that will act as a function, hence parentheses are removed, e.g. `__next__`.